# Нужно ли постоянно писать соединение с базой в запросе?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
// работает так
mysql_query(SELECT * FROM `my_table`,$bd);

// и так
mysql_query(SELECT * FROM `my_table`);
```

Отличие только в том, что в конце идет соединение с базой данных. Вопрос прост, нужно ли в каждом запросе писать соединение с бд? И если нужно иногда то когда?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**mysql_query()** посылает запрос активной базе данных сервера, на который ссылается переданный указатель. Если параметр **$bd** опущен, используется последнее открытое соединение. Если открытые соединения отсутствуют, функция пытается соединиться с СУБД, аналогично функции mysql_connect() без параметров. Результат запроса буфферизируется.

Если вы точно знаете, что используете одно открытое соединение, то этот параметр можно опускать, в противном случае лучше прописать его. А еще лучше пользоваться альтернативами данной функции:

- **mysqli_query()**
- **PDO::query()**

так как данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в будущем.

Comment: Спасибо всем кто ответил, но вот этот ответ аж вынуждает почитать/перейти про mysqli и PDO

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно, если база одна (в общем случае - работает с последним установленным соединением). О чём написано аж в первых же строках [руководства](http://www.php.su/mysql_query), однако.

Answer (score 2):

Открываем [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) и читаем:

> Если идентификатор соединения не был указан, используется последнее соединение, открытое mysql_connect(). Если такое соединение не было найдено, функция попытается создать таковое, как если бы mysql_connect() была вызвана без параметров. Если соединение не было найдено и не смогло быть создано, генерируется ошибка уровня E_WARNING.

Я бы порекомендовал ВСЕГДА указывать второй параметр. Так вы избежите путаницы, если вдруг в одном скрипте придётся открыть два разных соединения.